# Subsetting several data frames in R using the same condition but fewer lines of code

Tags: r, subset, data-cleaning

I have several data frames that have the same columns, but are split up by year. I want to drop rows in the data frames using the same conditions, but want to reduce the number of lines of code it takes me to do that.

```
df1
lat   long   ID
44    10     1
43    20     2
42    30     3
45    39     4

df2
lat   long   ID
47    10     1
44    20     2
46    30     3
43    39     4
```

For example, I only want to keep the observations where lat is greater than or equal to 44 and less than or equal to 45, and longs that are more than or equal to 10 and less than or equal to 30 (not actually the data Im working with, but you get the idea).

I want to avoid a ton of lines of code (a few lines for these example frames two doesn't seem like a lot, but I have 10 different data frames, each with millions of observations and I would like to keep them separate). I know loops are typically slow in R, so what's the best way to efficiently use the same function to subset several data frames without combining them.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the dataframes in a list and use `lapply` to subset them.

```
list_data <- list(df1, df2)
result <- lapply(list_data, subset, lat >= 44 & lat <= 45 & long >= 10 & long <= 30)
```

A `tidyverse` solution would be :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

result <- map(list_data, ~.x %>% filter(between(lat, 44, 45) & between(long, 10, 30)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ronak beat me to it, but here's a slightly different solution in `base R`

Put all of your dataframes into a list

```
dfs <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))
```

Create a function based on your parameters

```
your_func <- function(x){
  subset(x, lat %in% c(44,45) & long >= 10 & long <= 30)
}
```

Apply function to all dataframes in the list

```
dfs <- lapply(dfs, FUN = function(x) your_func(x))
```

Move your dataframes from list to global environment

```
list2env(dfs,globalenv())
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
list_data <- list(setDT(df1), setDT(df2))
result <- lapply(list_data, function(dt) dt[between(lat, 44, 45) & between(long, 10, 30)])
```